# Apostrophe In Regex

Tags: php, regex, validation

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the following regex as part of my form validation.

```
else if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;-]{5,60}$/', $locationname))
```

I must admit, it taken me sometime to get this far but I've come across which I've been unable to solve.

I just wondered whether somone could possibly tell me please how I could incorporate an apostrophe as an acceptable character in this regex expression.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Answer (score 3):

Escape the apostrophe with a backslash, `\'`:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;\'-]{5,60}$/', $locationname)
```

Comment: Hi @RitchieHindle, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and for the solution. I've implemented the change into my code and unfortuantely it doesn't appear to work because I'm unable to pass the apostrophe. I actually have two files where I need to make the changes with the originals

`"regex": /^$|^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;-]+$/`, and `preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;-]{5,60}$/', $locationname))` changed to:

`"regex": /^$|^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;\'-]+$/,` and `preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;\'-]{5,60}$/', $locationname)`

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping using \

> else if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;-\']{5,60}$/', $locationname))

Range - also needs to be escaped (\-). Try the following

```
else if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9 .,; \-\']{5,60}$/', $locationname))
```

Comment: Hi @Ram, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and for the suggested solution. I have tried to implement this, but unfortunately I receive a syntax error when I run the script. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: I have edited my comments by adding escape for the - (range). try this  now

Comment: Hi @Ram, thank you very much for your continued help with this. Unfortunately I couldn't get the script to work with your solution  but after some more work I've been able to get this to work with the solution I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

In additon to the help I received, after some more work with this I found the soluton to be: `else if(!preg_match('/^$|^[-a-zA-Z0-9 .,;\ \']{5,60}$/', $locationname)){`

Regards

Chris